# MS Access 2016 - If Statement returns incorrect value

Tags: vba, ms-access

This applies to a MS Access 2016 desktop application.  I have a form with an unbound textbox to accept user input.  I'm using the BeforeUpdate event to validate the user entry since the rules can be quite complex.  This is the BeforeUpdate event code:

```
Private Sub CarbonCountTBX_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)

Cancel = Not IsValidFormulaSubscript(Me!CarbonCountTBX)

End Sub
```

In its simplest form, a user entry of Null or an empty string is acceptable.  The function to test that is as follows:

```
Public Function IsValidFormulaSubscript(subscript As Variant) As Boolean

If IsNull(subscript) Or IsEmpty(subscript) Then
    IsValidFormulaSubcript = True
    Exit Function
End If

End Function
```

The net consequence should be that if the function IsValidFormulaSubscript returns true, the Beforeupdate event is NOT canceled.  For whatever reason, IsValidFormulaSubscript always returns exactly the opposite of what it should return.  I've tested this in the debugger as well and it still comes out wrong.  I'm baffled!  Any ideas of what is going wrong?

EDITED: ADD: If I reverse the code to
`Cancel = IsValidFormulaSubscript(Me!CarbonCountTBX)`
it works but that defeats the entire purpose of self-documenting code and is also illogical.  Also note that testing with IsEmpty has no affect since it is within an OR condition.  An IsNull or IsEmpty should produce the same result.

Comment: Is the typo in the return `IsValidFormulaSubcript` in your actual code? Should be `IsValidFormulaSubscript`

Comment: Remove the `IsEmpty()` condition.

Comment: There was a typo outside the code that has been corrected.  IsValidFormulaSubscript is correct.

Comment: The IsEmpty() test is necessary and works.  The debugger verifies that empty strings and nulls are being correctly passed.  For some reason, the function result is being reversed when it is called.

Comment: What exactly do you check with the `IsEmpty()` function? Please read the documentation of what it does. It certainly does not check for empty strings.

Comment: I'm checking for an uninitialized control value since no default is set and the control is unbound.  That value could be a string trimmed to zero length.  The code has NO problem with this test.  The problem is in the calling sub.

Comment: And you do realize that you set cancel = true to cancel - right?

Comment: The code is exactly as shown in the post.  If the subscript value IsNull, the function returns True and in BeforeUpdate code, the return value of True is set to NOT IsValidFormulaSubscript (false).  That is what should happen,

Answer (score 0):

I guess `subscript` should be something to true. And you pass a field/control which never is empty, so this should do:

```
Public Function IsValidFormulaSubscript(subscript As Variant) As Boolean

    IsValidFormulaSubcript = Not IsNull(subscript)

End Function
```

Comment: The control can be empty or null.  The function IsValidFormulaSubscript correctly evaluates this but for some reason, the function result is being reversed when it is called from the BeforeUpdate event.

Comment: Again, a control on a form can never be `Empty`, only an unassigned `Variant `variable can. Thus, only a check for _Null_ is needed. Why not simply use `Cancel =  IsNull(Me!CarbonCountTBX.Value)`?

Comment: Whether a control can be empty or not is purely academic (trimmed strings).  The test condition IsNull OR IsEmpty is working properly as verified in the debugger.  The result being returned is correct but for some reason it is being reveresed by the calling sub.

Comment: It is not academic, and an empty string is a third thing to bring in, not being the same as `Empty`. `IsNull` is the one and only thing needed to check for a control "not being filled in". The sub function cannot "reverse" anything, so most likely something else is going on.

Comment: You are missing a point.  If the control is not filled in, that is a perfectly valid value as much as a null or an empty string.  Since the IsEmpty test is coupled with the IsNull test in an OR condition, a null should and does produce a result of true.  Even when testing for a null value only, the problem persists.  The point is that the calling sub IS REVERSING the result.  As you say, something else is going on, but what, and why?  There is no other code attached to the form or control.  There are no validation rules and no input masks.  I've never encountered this problem before..

Comment: Sorry, I'm lost. If _Null_ is valid, why check for that? Check for the invalid value(s) whatever these are. I think you'll have to rephrase this completely to make your point clear.

Comment: As I mentioned in the post, IsNull or IsEmpty is the first in a series of validation tests.  If there is an entry, it needs to be tested further.  This code would apply to several other controls as well, hence I wrote it as a function.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the data types.  Returning a boolean to the BeforeUpdate event code as the setting for Cancel, an integer does not work.  Converting the boolean using CInt(boolean) does not work.  In Access, True = -1 and Cancel expects 1 or 0.  Here is the revised code that does work noting that I changed the name of the function to maintain some degree of self-documentation.

```
Private Sub CarbonCountTBX_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)

Cancel = IsNotValidFormulaSubscript(Me!CarbonCountTBX)

End Sub
```

and

```
Public Function IsNotValidFormulaSubscript(subscript As Variant) As Integer

If IsNull(subscript) Or IsEmpty(subscript) Then
    IsNotValidFormulaSubscript = 0
    Exit Function
End If

'additional tests and fall through

IsNotValidFormulaSubscript = 1

End Function
```